# Java regular expression usage

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace two or more variables in a string. I am able to replace one at a time in a single expression, but how can we replace two or more in a single time.

for example; the line the dog says meow needs to be changed to the cat says bow.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches
{
private static String REGEX = "dog";
private static String INPUT = "The dog says meow. ";
private static String REPLACE = "cat";

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
   // get a matcher object
   Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT); 
   INPUT = m.replaceAll(REPLACE);
   System.out.println(INPUT);
}
}
```

the above code changes the expression to "The cat says meow" but I need "The cat says bow".

Comment: And you never mention "bow" in your code, how is it surprising that you don't get the right output ?

Comment: There is no convenient method available. You need to write Matcher loop to do this in one pass, though I am not sure about performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another replace or replaceAll function with the first `replaceAll` function like below.

```
private static String REGEX = "dog";
private static String INPUT = "The dog says meow. ";
private static String REPLACE = "cat";

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
   // get a matcher object
   Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT); 
   INPUT = m.replaceAll(REPLACE).replace("meow", "bow");
   System.out.println(INPUT);
```

Output:

```
The cat says bow.
```

OR

```
INPUT = m.replaceAll(REPLACE).replaceAll("me(?=ow\\b)", "b");
```

`me(?=ow\\b)` matches the sub-string `me` only if it's followed by `ow` plus a word boundary. Then the `replaceAll` function replaces the string `me` with `b` in the resulted string of  first `replaceAll` function call.

Comment: This is such a hack :) The second replacement in the first example does not even use regex.

Comment: While the second one does not use regex, it goes through Pattern class internally for Oracle/OpenJDK implementation.

Comment: @nhahtdh The second example does use regex, it's the second replacement in the first example that doesn't.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: It doesn't use regex upfront, but you pay the price of regex when you use it, for Oracle/OpenJDK implementation.

Comment: @nhahtdh I mean specifically the `.replace("meow", "bow")` part.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: And I am also referring to that part: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#String.replace%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%29 No regex, but you pay the price for it.